# embedding external css and script in python cgi shows 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: python, apache, cgi, cgi-bin

My program directory:

```
     xampp
       |- cgi-bin
            |- home.py
            |- style.css
            |- script.js
```

In home.py i embeded `style.css` and `script.css`

```
print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print '<html>'
print ' <head>'
print '     <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">'
print '     <title>Home</title>'
print '     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">'
print '     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">           </script>'
print '     <script src="script.js"></script>'
```

But it doesn't work and in my console it shows :

`"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost/cgi-bin/script.js"` & 
`"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost/cgi-bin/style.js"`

**Another Case:**

I tried `/style.css` and `/script.js` while embedding:

RESULTS

`"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/style.css"
 "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/script.js"`

tried `/cgi-bin/style.css` and `cgi-bin/script.css` shows the *500 internal server error* with absolute path

Tried using absolute path: `http://localhost/cgi-bin/style.css` and `http://localhost/cgi-bin/script.js` also shows the same *500 internal server error*

Whereas jquery is working fine with CDN.

is there something i haven't configured or is there some other way around ?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript and CSS should not be in a cgi-bin, which serves files (typically with `.cgi` or - in your case - `.py` extensions) as cgi *scripts*. Instead, `.js` and `.css` files are usually in the website root folder or (for a Python app) served as static files in `my_site_root/html/js/` from somewhere public-readable by the app like `my_app/public/`.

So your cgi-bin shouldn't serve files directly readable via a web browser, like Javascript and CSS files. XAMPP will be set up that way by default.

The CDN URL will *always* work because it's making an http call to an external server - it doesn't look in your locally-served XAMPP install.